# Como puedo hacer una consulta que sume y reste en una tabla

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "paypal");
    /* verificar la conexión */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Conexión fallida:" . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $sq = "INSERT INTO montos (usuario, monto) VALUES ('Andres', (SELECT SUM(monto ) montos FROM datos WHERE id IN (1,2)) )";    
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sq);
    if ($result > 0 ) {
        $sql = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE datos SET monto = monto - 50 WHERE id = 2 ");
    }
?>
```

Quiero saber sí puedo unir las dos consultas hacer una consulta general la primera suma y la otra realiza una resta y actualiza el campo que se esta utilizando.

Comment: Podrías emplear un trigger, lo programas que se ejecute cada "X" acción, en tu caso una suma o resta. Saludos.

Comment: gracias lo voy a intentar

Comment: pienso que seria mas conveniente que fuese en un procedimiento almancenado, ya que solo estamos tomando en cuenta 1 solo esenario que ese que todos las transacciones dentro de esa tabla van a tener el mismo resultado, y con procedimiento almacemando se va a ejecutar en el momento que sea necesario en cambio con un trigger siempre que se ejecute un insert se ejecutara, y en el caso de que no sea requerido de igual amnera

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar este `trigger` para lo que mencionas que necesitar hacer:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER nombreTrigger BEFORE INSERT ON tuTabla
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    //tu codigo 
    UPDATE datos SET monto = monto - 50 WHERE id = 2
  END
|

DELIMITER ;
```

Saludos.